# Can't install WSO2 for PHP on Windows x64 -- PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\wsf.dll'

Tags: php, wso2

I think I have followed the installation instructions, but obviously I have missed something.  Basically, with the DLL in the php.ini file, I get:

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\wsf.dll'

Without it, all starts fine.  Here's some highlights from phpinfo:

```
PHP Version 5.4.6

extension_dirext ext ext

include_path: .;c:\php\includes;C:\PHP\wso2-wsf-php-bin-2.1.0-win32\scripts
```

Path :

```
c:\php;C:\PHP\wso2-wsf-php-bin-2.1.0-win32\wsf_c\lib;c:\php\ext;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Windows\idmu\common;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;



WSFC_HOME : C:\PHP\wso2-wsf-php-bin-2.1.0-win32\wsf_c 

From the php.ini:
[wsf] 
wsf.home="C:\PHP\wso2-wsf-php-bin-2.1.0-win32\wsf_c" 
wsf.log_path="C:\PHP\wso2-wsf-php-bin-2.1.0-win32\wsf_c\logs\" 
wsf.log_level=4 

wsf.rm_db_dir="C:\windows\temp\"
```

I've also watched the process while trying to start PHP in Process Monitor.   I see c:\php\ext\wsf.dll loaded.  Then it starts down a list of dependencies, looking along the path and finding most of them in the lib folder.

```
C:\PHP\wso2-wsf-php-bin-2.1.0-win32\wsf_c\lib\axutil.dll
C:\PHP\wso2-wsf-php-bin-2.1.0-win32\wsf_c\lib\axis2_engine.dll
C:\PHP\wso2-wsf-php-bin-2.1.0-win32\wsf_c\lib\axiom.dll
C:\PHP\wso2-wsf-php-bin-2.1.0-win32\wsf_c\lib\axis2_parser.dll
C:\PHP\wso2-wsf-php-bin-2.1.0-win32\wsf_c\lib\guththila.dll
C:\PHP\wso2-wsf-php-bin-2.1.0-win32\wsf_c\lib\neethi.dll
C:\PHP\wso2-wsf-php-bin-2.1.0-win32\wsf_c\lib\rampart.dll
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\libeay32.dll
C:\PHP\wso2-wsf-php-bin-2.1.0-win32\wsf_c\lib\neethi_util.dll
C:\PHP\wso2-wsf-php-bin-2.1.0-win32\wsf_c\lib\sandesha2_client.dll
```

writes to the error log:

```
[12-Sep-2012 12:48:12 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\wsf.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found. in Unknown on line 0
```

Continues:

```
C:\PHP\ext\php_xsl.dll
```

And the last thing I see is some failed attempts at reading registry keys that are not there, the Per Directory Values Key is what it's after.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid wso2 for PHP is not compatible with PHP 5.4
I tried to compile wso2 extension for PHP on linux and succeeded only with PHP 5.3.
There is the same issue for windows probably.

You can try to downgrade your PHP to version 5.3 and check if it'll work in this case.

I should also warn you not to use this extension in production because of the following reasons:

- the latest commit to their [repo](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/wsf/php/) was made almost a year ago
- there is no progress in their [JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/WSFPHP) either for about a year
- the person who is set as a project manager for this project in jira seems to work on another project right now
- they are not responding to bug report in jira
- this extension has known stability issues on linux (check stackoverflow or their jira with keyworkds "wso2 php segmentation fault")

On the recent project we are also supposed to use wso2 php extension, but after some research we see that this extension is unstable and not supported anymore.
Unfortunately, for now we do not know what to use instead and looking for some other solutions.